# Flask page keeps performing GET request after jQuery .show()

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask

I have one div with a form shown and one div with a table hidden. When I clicked the NEXT button, it would use some jQuery to pull info off the form and populate the table, while simultaneously hiding the form div and showing the table div.

However, now I'm trying to hook it up to a Flask API, and I got the page to display, but when I click NEXT the form div is hidden and the table is populated and shown, but then it immediately disappears and goes back to the form (the server side shows that it's doing a GET request right after I click next and the populated table shows and immediately disappears). How can I stop it from performing the GET request and just populate the table, awaiting the another button click? Is the GET request just something that happens automatically when I pull stuff off the form using jQuery?

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/jdrequest_form.css') }}">
    </head>
  <body>

    <div class = "header">
      <div id=inner> <h1>Grand Valley Water Users Association</h1> </div>
    </div> 

    <form class="grid-container">
      <section class="title box"><h3>Water Request</h3></section>

      <section class="serial-label spec-label">Serial Number</section>
      <section class="serial-input spec-input-serial">
        <input type="text" name="serialNum">
      </section>

      <!-- A BUNCH MORE INPUT BOXES WITH LABELS... -->

      <section class="send-request box"><button class="nextBtn">Next</button></section>
    </form>

    <!--
      Start of Confirmation Page
      This is hidden by default and appears in place of the Water Request Form
      when the "Next" button is clicked (via the JavaScript file) 
    -->
    <div class = "confirm">
      <div class = "confirmInstructions">
      <p>Please review your order carefully before submitting it.</p>
      </div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Serial Number:</td>
            <td id="serial-num"></td>
          </tr>
          <!-- A BUNCH MORE TABLE ENTRIES -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="edit-submit">
        <button class="editBtn">Edit Request</button>
        <button class="submit-btn" href="/">Submit Request</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jdrequest_form.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
/*  
*   Upon clicking the "Next" button, this will hide the request form 
*   and copy all of the values from the form into a table for the
*   client to review. 
*/
$("button.nextBtn").click(function(){
  $(".grid-container").hide();

  $("#serial-num").text($("[name='serialNum']").val());
  /* AND A BUNCH MORE OF THE SAME SORT OF THING*/

  $(".confirm").show();
});

$("button.editBtn").click(function(){
  $(".confirm").hide();
  $(".grid-container").show();
});
```

And here's the Flask I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
# initialize database with settings from app
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Form_Items(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  serial_num = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
  # AND A BUNCH OF OTHERS THAT DON'T MATTER

  # IGNORE THIS. I HAVEN'T MESSED WITH IT YET
  def __repr__(self):
    return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def jdrequest_form():
  if request.method=='POST':
    # A BUNCH OF DATABASE STUFF THAT DOESN'T MATTER

  else:
    return render_template('jdrequest_form.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Finally, here is what the Flask app says in ther terminal right when I click the NEXT button:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2020 17:45:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2020 17:45:30] "GET /static/js/jdrequest_form.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2020 17:45:30] "GET /static/css/jdrequest_form.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2020 17:45:48] "GET /?serialNum=45645&meterReading=456&requestType=Change&sF=456&changefromsF=456&changetosF=456&date=2020-03-10&lateral=456&turnout=456&remarks=xfzxcfgszfgdf&name=zsdfd+asdf HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I don't want any requests to happen until I actually click the SUBMIT REQUEST button (which currently does nothing, but the EDIT REQUEST button should hide the table and bring the form back up, without requests, right?).
If anyone has any idea where I've gone wrong, I'd love to hear it so I can get this project rolling along again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is your form is performing its default GET request when you hit the submit button. To prevent its default behavior:

```
$("button.nextBtn").click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! That tiny bit of code was a HUGE save! I didn't think about that with the button being in the form. Brilliant.